# page reload jquery countdown

Tags: jquery, reload, countdown

I have the following code..

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        /* Refresh every minute */
        setInterval(function () { cache_clear() }, 60000);
    });
    function cache_clear() {
        window.location.reload(true);
    }
</script>
```

It reload the page every minute, it would be nice to have a countdown function added to this so the user can see how long to next reload. But I could use some help with that.

Comment: Have you had a look to this jQuery plugin? http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can maintain a variable and decrement it. Use interval as 1000 milliseconds, which is 1 second. Once the counter is 0, call `cache_clear`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var count = 60;
   setInterval(function(){
      $('body').text("Reload in " + (count--) + "secs");
      if(count == 0) cache_clear();
   }, 1000)
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/g9jfo911/)